# Change Class based on active record db query with link_to in loop in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Requesting expert help.

I have an applications table which has_many metrics.

At some point of time, metrics will have following kind of records.

{capture_time:"08:00:10.1234",metric_name:"log",metric_value:"OK",application_id:1}
{capture_time:"09:00:10.1234",metric_name:"process",metric_value:"KO",application_id:1}
{capture_time:"10:00:10.1234",metric_name:"process",metric_value:"OK",application_id:1}

{capture_time:"08:00:10.1234",metric_name:"log",metric_value:"OK",application_id:2}
{capture_time:"09:00:10.1234",metric_name:"process",metric_value:"OK",application_id:2}
{capture_time:"10:00:10.1234",metric_name:"process",metric_value:"KO",application_id:2}

I have a bigger loop for applications and for each application , I create buttons for each metric for that application

```
<% applic.metric.uniq{|p|p.metric_name}.each do |m| %>
<%= link_to m.metric_name, metrics_path(m.application_id,metric_name: m.metric_name) , :class=>"btn btn-success",:role=>"button" %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

On clicking any button it shows me records only for that metrics. For e.g. if I click on process, i see all records of that metric, which is 2 records in my case.

[image]

So till here its fine. What I am looking help for is two folds:

1. How to determine latest metrics(based in capture time) for that application that is KO and then use that to change the class in link_to inside the loop. Something like this:

> ```
> <% applic.metric.uniq{|p|p.metric_name}.each do |m| %>
> <%= link_to m.metric_name, metrics_path(m.application_id,metric_name: m.metric_name),:class=>"btn btn-success",:role=>"button" %>    
> <% end %>
> ```

***Class => btn-danger if latest record for this metric was KO else btn-success***

[image]

2. Then I would want to use the combined statuses of the Metrices and change the Class for the whole Application1 box.
   For e.g if any one of Process, Log, Errorcounts is failed , which means any of the latest matrices of any of 3 category is KO, then the whole Application1 box should have a class as "btn-danger"

like this:
[image]

**UPDATE 1 : Many Thanks to @sammms**

I tried the suggestion and created following, but it still does not solve my problem.

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :application

  def isFailed(metric_value=nil)
    metric_value == 'KO'
  end
end

<% applic.metric.uniq{|p|p.metric_name}.each do |metric| %>
    <%= link_to metric.metric_name, application_dashboard_metrics_path(appid:metric.application_id,metric_name: metric.metric_name), 
    {:class=>"btn #{metric.isFailed(metric.metric_value)? 'btn-danger':'btn-success' }",:role=>"button"} %>
<% end %>
```

the string interpolation works, as in it changes the class based on metric value.  But the problem is in uniq bit here.

```
applic.metric.uniq{|p|p.metric_name}.each
```

since I am looping through only the unique metric_name, it could be the one with metric_value as OK. And hence when it loops, it actually does not find any KO for that metric.

If I don't use uniq in the loop, then I see one button for each record. something like below,

[image]

This is not what I wanted.
I wanted to have a button only once, per metric_name, then change the class based on the collective status of all the records for that metric.

So, when I have 100 record for process metric, I don't want 100 buttons, I want only one process button, but the class should be based on if the latest metric_value is KO.

**UPDATE 2:**

I solved the problem with this:

```
def isFailed(metric_name=nil)
    p metric_name
    #metric_value == 'KO'
    Metric.where(metric_name:metric_name).order("capture_time DESC").first.metric_value == "KO"
end
```

Now I need to figure out the part 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inside of an ERB block `<%=... %>` you can write vanilla ruby and it will be evaluated.  That means you can used interpolation inside the string you pass to `class`, e.g. 
`class="#{'btn-danger' if metric.ko?}"` 
where `ko?` is a method defined in `Metric` that will return the boolean used to evaluate your condition.  eg...

```
class Metric
  def ko?
    metric_value == 'KO'
  end
end
```

For the second part, you could use the same logic.  Create a CSS class that makes your box look the way you want it to look, then conditionally add it using string interpolation in the ERB class definition.  Then just define a method on the Class (I think it sounds like you would want the application class in this case so you can evaluate it's associated metrics) and use that to return a boolean.

Comment: Thank you very much,I tried your suggestion. there is still some problem. So I am adding as update to my question as there is restriction in comments space.